Kotlin custom serialization - Linear json structure for nested data classes
I have a couple of data classes like below
data class Base (
  val prop1: String,
  val prop2: String
)

data class Derived (
  val base: Base,
  val prop3: String
)

The serialized form of Derived type looks like this
{
  "prop1": "value1",
  "prop2": "value2",
  "prop3": "value3"
}

I can write custom serializers using kotlinx for the derived class, but I'll be having many classes like Derived class which will have a field of Base type. I don't want to write custom serializer and de-serializer for every one of the type.
What options do I have? I'm just looking for more convenient ways to add new types, without writing custom serializers for each of them.
Any other libraries solve this problem? jackson?

It doesn't seem possible with kotlinx.serialization at present without writing a custom serializer. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556699/serialize-kotlin-nested-classes-to-flat-json and https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/292. Maybe some other library can do it.

Thanks. Then for now, I'll be making this base class an interface/sealed class and create new types overriding this.
